# python data and non-data descriptors

Tags: python, descriptor, python-descriptors

According to [Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors),

> Data descriptors with `__set__()` and `__get__()` defined always override a redefinition in an instance dictionary.

I have no problem understanding this sentence, but can someone clarify for me why such a rule is in place?  After all, if I want to override an attribute in an instance dictionary, I already need to do that *explicitely* (`inst.__dict__["attr"] = val`), as a naive `inst.attr = val` would call the descriptor's `__set__` method, which would (usually) not override the attribute in the instance dictionary.

edit: just to make it clear, I understand what is happening, my question is about why such a rule was put in place.

Answer (score 10):

The override applies to descriptors that are part of the *class* `__dict__`.

Python will always look up `type(instance).__dict__[attributename].__get__(instance, type(instance))`, and will *not* use `instance.__dict__` to search for a instance-override.

Here is an example using a contrived `Descriptor` class and a property (which is a descriptor with a `__get__` and a `__set__`:

```
>>> class Descriptor(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def __get__(self, instance, cls):
...         print 'Getting %s, with instance %r, class %r' % (self.name, instance, cls)
... 
>>> class Foo(object):
...     _spam = 'eggs'
...     @property
...     def spam(self):
...         return self._spam
...     @spam.setter
...     def spam(self, val):
...         self._spam = val
... 
>>> Foo().spam
'eggs'
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.__dict__['spam'] = Descriptor('Override')
>>> foo.spam
'eggs'
```

As you can see, even though I add a `spam` entry in the instance `__dict__`, it is completely ignored and the `Foo.spam` property is used still. Python is ignoring the instance `__dict__` because the `spam` property defines both `__get__` and a `__set__`.

If you use a descriptor that *doesn't* define a `__set__` the override works (but it's `__get__` is not called:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     desc = Descriptor('Class-stored descriptor')
... 
>>> Foo.desc
Getting Class-stored descriptor, with instance None, class <class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo().desc
Getting Class-stored descriptor, with instance <__main__.Foo object at 0x1018df510>, class <class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.__dict__['desc'] = Descriptor('Instance-stored descriptor')
>>> foo.desc
<__main__.Descriptor object at 0x1018df1d0>
```

Comment: can u explain with an example?

Comment: Here's the implementation for CPython 2.7.3: [get](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Objects/object.c#l1382) and [set](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Objects/object.c#l1494). The order is data descriptor, instance attribute, non-data descriptor, and finally (get only) a class attribute.

Comment: Yes, I already understood that part.  My question was more about the *rationale* for such a rule; i.e., I will never "accidentally" override a class' data descriptor in an instance (i.e. to do so I need to access __dict__) so why forbid me to do so if I really want to?

Comment: @antony: this is a concious decision, for a longer explanation see [PEP 252](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0252/); but the short of it is so that you cannot override static attributes like `__class__` in the instance `__dict__`.

Comment: @antony: or, put differently, if a descriptor has `__set__` defined, it is interested in intercepting assignment (including denying assignment, making it a read-only attribute). To this end it is given precedence; Python cannot detect if the descriptor is allowing writing the attribute (`__set__` will not raise an exception) and thus the instance `__dict__` value cannot override it, as that would allow you to circumvent such a descriptor.

Comment: Still not convinced (again, my point is that Python's approach is usually one of "consenting adults" and that fiddling with `__dict__` should get you, well, what you want -- if I wanted to dynamically update an attribute while respecting the descriptor protocol I can use `setattr`) but I guess I should not argue on language design here.

Comment: @antony: I tend to agree that the 'nanny' rationales (read-only attributes, preventing nonsense like shadowing a ctypes Structrue field, etc) are weak. However, it would be inefficient to always have to find the instance dict and lookup the attribute, just for the rare desire to override a data descriptor. There's nothing stopping you from checking the instance manually in the descriptor methods.

Comment: On the contrary, the implemented approach looks less efficient to me: you must now check the type dict for a data descriptor, then the instance dict for a non-descriptor attribute, and then the type dict again for a non-data descriptor.

Comment: @antony: It only calls `_PyType_Lookup(tp, name)` once, which caches recently accessed attributes, including `NULL` if the name wasn't found in the bases.

Comment: But without this rule you wouldn't need to call this even once if the attribute is found in the instance dict.  (note: I don't really think performance is a good argument here, it's not as if this was the slowest part of python :))