# Under what scenario non-data descriptor may NOT be overridden by instance dictionaries

Tags: python, descriptor

In the section "Invoking Descriptors" of [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors), it says:

"
data descriptors always override instance dictionaries.

**non-data descriptors may be overridden by instance dictionaries.**
"

And it also says:

"
The implementation works through a precedence chain that **gives data descriptors priority over instance variables, instance variables priority over non-data descriptors,** and assigns lowest priority to __getattr__() if provided. 
"

Then, the non-data descriptor should **alway**s be overridden by instance dictionaries. Why it use "**may be**" here? How should I understand this statement?

Comment: It says *"may be"* because you might not have anything in the instance dictionary to override them, **not** because if you had something in the instance dictionary to override them they ever *wouldn't* be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following configuration:

```
class data_descriptor:
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        return 'data descriptor'
    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        pass

class non_data_descriptor:
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        return 'non data descriptor'

class X:
    attr_data = data_descriptor()
    attr_non_data = non_data_descriptor()
```

The data descriptor takes precedence **regardless of whether or not you have an item in the instance dictionary**.  However, the **non-data descriptor can be shadowed** by an item in the instance dictionary.  The docs only write "may be overridden" because it depends on whether or not there is a colliding key present in the instance dictionary.

Here's a demo:

```
>>> x = X()
>>> x.attr_data
'data descriptor'
>>> x.attr_non_data
'non data descriptor'
>>> # populate the instance dict with stuff
>>> x.__dict__.update({'attr_data': 'spam', 'attr_non_data': 'eggs'})  
>>> x.attr_data  # descriptor wins
'data descriptor'
>>> x.attr_non_data  # instance __dict__ wins
'eggs'
>>> del x.attr_non_data  # restore descriptor by removing name from __dict__
>>> x.attr_non_data
'non data descriptor'
```

For a discussion of *why* the descriptor protocol was designed this way, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13007179/674039).